# upload file from android to laravel php server

Tags: java, php, android, laravel-5.1

This is my php laravel code to change/upload image. I want to upload file from android device. I have server side code only. how to send file from android???

```
//change org logo
    public function change_orgLogo() {

        $input = Input::all();

        $file = Input::file('file');

        if ($file) {
            $destinationPath = 'images/org_logo/'.Input::get('org_id').'/';
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            $picUrl = 'images/org_logo/'.Input::get('org_id').'/'.$filename;
        } else {
            $picUrl = Organizationinfo::where("id", Input::get('org_id'))->pluck("logo");
            $upload_success = true;
        }

        if (Input::get('company_name') != null && Input::get('company_name') != "") {
            $cmpName = Input::get('company_name');
        } else {
            $cmpName = Organizationinfo::where("id", Input::get('org_id'))->pluck("name");
        }

        if ($upload_success) {
            $res = Organizationinfo::where('id', Input::get('org_id'))->update(['logo' => $picUrl, 'name' => $cmpName]);

            if ($res)
                return Redirect::back()->with('Changes saved successfully');
            else
                return Redirect::back()->with('Error while changing image');

        } else {
            return Redirect::back()->with('Error while changing image');
        }
    }
```

This is my client side code to post request to server.

```
//edit org info
    private class EditOrgInfo extends RemoteDataExporter {
        String choice;

        public EditOrgInfo(Context appContext) {
            super(editOrgURL, UserManagementActivity.this);
            this.choice = choice;
        }

        @Override
        HashMap<String, String> buildMapFromValue() {
            HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();

            maps.put(TAG_NAME, edt_org_name.getText().toString());
            return maps;
        }

        @Override
        void processPostExecute() {

        }
    }
```